# Memory fading “striyers” in viscoelastics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

I was talking to a guy who does polymer moulding, and we were discussing a few industrial issues in melting, mixing and forming shapes, and with a few of my suggestions he rebutted with, "no that would create striyers". So for example, one mixing technique I suggested had the fluid melt pass through a grate at the end, and he didn't like that idea because it would create striyers.

My understanding at the time, from the context, was that he was referring to the viscoelastic nature of the fluid, that has a (fading) memory component. So in my example the product might still have lines far downstream left over from passing through the grate. But I've not heard this word "striyer", and wondered if anybody knows what it is?!

We were speaking in English, but if it helps, his mother tongue is German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Striation? ...Striations means a series of ridges, furrows or linear marks

Comment: Ooh, this sounds like an excellent fit!

Answer (score 2):

What he is getting at is that, after the grate, the polymer molecules that passed on either side of the grate take time to "knit back together" again (i.e., form entanglements).  So the structure of the polymer is temporarily weakened.